# Change size of Fig in bqplot?

Tags: python, jupyter, bqplot

I'm new to [bqplot](http://bqplot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Trying to figure out how to resize a figure. I tried both of the following, lightly modifying example code:

```
fig = Figure(marks=[line], axes=[ax_x, ax_y], title='Security 1')
fig.height = 100
```

and

```
fig = Figure(marks=[line], axes=[ax_x, ax_y], title='Security 1', height = 100)
```

Neither of these is showing any effect. Is there a way to change the size of a `bqplot`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the parameters `min_width` and `min_height`?

Comment: My plots are too big so I didn't see the point of those parameters in solving my problem, but you're right, I'll give that  try.

Comment: It should work, since if you want a large figure, just set the min_height (the minimum height of the Figure)

Answer (score 3):

Use the layout object.  Height must be expressed as a str with either 'px' or '%'. See example below.

```
fig = Figure(marks=[line], axes=[ax_x, ax_y], title='Security 1')
fig.layout.height = '100px'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also adjust the margins using fig_margin, ie:

`Figure(marks=[graph], fig_margin={'top':30, 'bottom':30, 'left':0, 'right':0})`